# Bootstrap dropdown menu doesn't open

Tags: html, css

Navber code:

```html
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light" style="background-color: #FDFEFF;">
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-center" id="navbarNav">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
            <img src="images\logo1.png" width="200" height="80" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt="">
          </a>
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
              <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
              </li>
              <li class="navbar-nav dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                  Behandelingen
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="sportmassage.html">Sportmassage</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Massagetherapie</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Ontspanningsmassage</a>
                </div>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Afspraak maken</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Tarieven</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
```

Bootstrap code:

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Dropdown menu inside the navbar doesn't open, anyone an idea on how to fix this?
Not very experienced with bootstrap and don't now what the problem is.

Comment: What version of jquery are you using?

Comment: Did you include the JavaScript files for Bootstrap and jQuery? What errors do you get in the console?

Answer (score 0):

Your button don't call your div

```
<button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
 Dropdown button
</button>
<div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
</div>
</div>
```

your "aria-labelledby" does not match the button id "id="dropdownMenuButton""

it's in the bootstrap documentation

Answer (score 0):

Try this for Bootstrap 4 dropdown navbar

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light" style="background-color: #fdfeff;">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
    <img src="images\logo1.png" width="200" height="80" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt="">
  </a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navCollapse"
    aria-controls="navCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-center" id="navCollapse">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="navbar-nav dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdown01"
          data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Behandelingen
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown01">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="sportmassage.html">Sportmassage</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Massagetherapie</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Ontspanningsmassage</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Afspraak maken</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Tarieven</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score -1):

Nevermind I solved the issue, stupid mistake by not adding jquery

Comment: This is should be a comment not an answer